# Does the sequence made up by terms of a series provide any clues as to whether the series itself is convergent or not?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the sequence of terms of the series (not the sequence of partial sums, just the sequence of successive terms) provide any information about whether a series is convergent or not?

I realize that the divergence or convergence of the sequence of partial sums of a series dictates whether or not the series is divergent or convergent. Is the sequence of partial sums related to the sequence of terms in any way?

Edit: I'm aware that there are tests that you can apply that involve these ideas and can tell you the divergent or convergent status of a series, but I don't have an intuitive understanding of how those tests really work. And instead of jumping ahead to understanding the tests, I was hoping to see if I'm missing anything more fundamental when it comes to series: thus this question. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you've heard of the ratio test or root test, then I think this answers your question.

Comment: @Clayton Ahh yes, I'm aware of the following tests: integral, ratio, root, comparison, limit comparison, and alternating series. Not sure if there are others. But unfortunately my experience with those amounts to just utilizing formulas and solving algebra problems; I lack an intuitive understanding as to how the ideas surrounding the concept of a series relate to each other, hence my question. Thanks for the response by the way!

Comment: No problem; I expanded on the explanation and hopefully provided some intuition in an answer. @James Ronald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone knows the test for divergence, and hopefully that makes intuitive sense (adding up infinitely many "far-from-zero" numbers should diverge to infinity or negative infinity).

Aside from that, two of the most common tests that are used to determine convergence or divergence of a series that relies solely on the information of the individual terms is ratio and root tests. The intuition behind these tests is determining how close to a geometric pattern the terms are. For example, consider the ratio test for a convergent series $\sum a_n$. The test states that if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=L,$$ then the series converges absolutely if $L<1$, diverges if $L>1$, and could do either in the case $L=1$. To see why, observe that by the definition of limit, we have $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1-\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ and all $n$ sufficiently large (say, $n\geq100$ just for argument's sake). Then for any $N>100$, we have $$|a_N|<(1-\varepsilon)^{N-100}|a_{100}|.$$ Now, just using the direct comparison test, you can see that adding up all of the absolute values on the left will be less than a geometric series on the right; in fact, this shows more clearly why the ratio test has its precise conclusion: geometric series diverge when the ratio is greater than $1$ and converge when it's less than $1$. Since our ratio test is only an approximation to a geometric series, we lose out on some information when the ratio is actually equal to $1$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thank you so much! It's extremely insightful to know that what the ratio and root tests are doing is just applying the rules of geometric series to more general types of series. This is very helpful, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to an advanced calculus text, look at the proofs and you will get a good idea about all those tests and a few more.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most fundamental results is that, for the series to converge, the sequence of individual terms must go to zero.

Other than that, see @Clayton's remark.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A series is convergent only if the terms of the series go to $0$. An intuitive way to see this is that, if we're adding infinite positive terms, the only way we finish with something that it's not infinite is if we are adding things that are infinitesimally small (in the sense that they are as small as we want).

However, note that his condition is necessary, but not suficient. The series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}$$

is divergent, although it's terms go to zero. So, it is necessary that the terms of the series tend to zero in a "sufficiently fast" way. What the tests you mentioned do is to say if the terms are going to zero in a way that is fast enough to the make the series converge.

Comment: Ah okay, it's helpful to justify it as not tending to zero "fast enough" as I didn't have any other intuitive way to explain that. Thank you for the help!